# Dynamic casting for TSharedPtr<Type>

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unreal-engine5

i have to change my code from using `std::shared_ptr<Type>` to `TSharedPtr<Type>` (so i can use unreal engine's delegates properly), but there is a problem - i can't find function to replace `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<To>(std::shared_ptr<From>)`, there is only a `StaticCastSharedPtr<To>(TSharedPtr<From>)`, but i need to be able to check if the object is of derived type in runtime, static casting won't help with that, am i missing something?

Comment: You can always try to emulate it as `dynamic_cast<To*>(from.get()) ? StaticCastSharedPtr<To>(from) : TSharedPtr<To>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do dynamic casting in Unreal Engine is just to simply call the [Cast](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/Templates/Cast/) function. In case you're curious, that function returns `TCastImpl<From, To>::DoCast(Src)`, and the `DoCast` function is implemented as follows as of UE 5.0,

```
// This is the cast flags implementation
FORCEINLINE static To* DoCast( UObject* Src )
{
    return Src && Src->GetClass()->HasAnyCastFlag(TCastFlags<To>::Value) ? (To*)Src : nullptr;
}
```

In UE 4.25 and below, before using cast flags, `DoCast` would call `IsA` instead to determine whether a pointer could be safely casted. Now it just uses bitwise operations between the source and destination object types' cast flags to see if the cast can be done.

Quick example: Assuming I had a custom `AActor` class called `AWizard` and a variable of type `AActor*` called `SomeActor`, may or may not be a wizard actor.

```
if (AWizard* Wizard= Cast<AWizard>(SomeActor)) {
    // Cast succeeded
}
else {
    // Cast returned nullptr
}
```